# I want to compress html/img/js data for mobile web page

Tags: web, compression

I just made testing version web http://www.stipendije.ba/mobile and in average it's 8 to 200kb per loaded page. Ofcourse, images takes the most. I wonder is there a way to compress js/jquery and images little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compress all your HTML traffic (if using Apache httpd) with this in your .htaccess or httpd.conf:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml
```

You can compress JS with any number of things.  YUI is good for JS and CSS compression.  If you don't want to download/compile your own version, you can use an online version at:

- http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/

There are lots of other things to look at if you don't like YUI. A lot of people use UglifyJS. Some people like [JSMin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) and some people go all whole-hog and use Google's Closure.

If you want to compress on the fly, you can use the Mobile Web Framework or model your own on-the-fly compressors on MWF's JS, CSS, and img minifiers/compressors.

- https://github.com/ucla/mwf
- especially https://github.com/ucla/mwf/tree/master/root/assets/min